# How can i change the label of page from another page?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, label

UPDATE: I have MainWindow, UC1 and UC2. Mainwindow contains frame1 and UCbutton than will show UC1 to the frame.

MainWindow:

```
<Frame Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="Frame1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" />
<Button Content="Show Usercontrol" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,216,0,0" Name="SUbutton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

VB:

```
Private Sub SUbutton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles SUbutton.Click
    Dim uc1 As New UC1
    Frame1.Navigate(uc1)
End Sub
```

then upon openning UC1 there consists of textbox and button

UC1:

```
<TextBlock Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,45,0,0" Text="Page1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" />
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,77,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
<Button Content="Show Usercontrol2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,106,0,0" Name="SU2button" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

VB:

```
Private Sub SU2button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles SU2button.Click
    Dim mainWindow = GetParentWindow(Me)
    If mainWindow IsNot Nothing Then
        mainWindow.Frame1.Navigate(New UC2())
    End If
End Sub
Private Shared Function GetParentWindow(ByVal obj As DependencyObject) As MainWindow
    While obj IsNot Nothing
        Dim mainWindow = TryCast(obj, MainWindow)
        If mainWindow IsNot Nothing Then
            Return mainWindow
        End If
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj)
    End While
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

what i need is for the text in the textbox will be displayed in Label at UC2

UC2:

```
<TextBlock Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,92,0,0" Name="hello" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" />
```

I already got help in navigating in to two page but i'm having a hard time learning Trycast or Directcast. :( Hope you could help me guys. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var wnd = Window.GetWindow(this);
            ((StackOverflow.MainWindow)(wnd)).Label1.Content = "sadasd";
        }

Comment: Madhabendra, a follow a question. what if it is from page to another page? is it possible? not in a mainwindow. hmmm. thanks!

Comment: You can check this..var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
        while (!(parent is Page))
        {
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }

Comment: thanks for helping @Mahabendra and freschx. I've updated my question because i missed including having two pages. hope u cud still help me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use events.

In your child window (Page1) code create an event like the following.

```
Public Event Textchanged(sender as object, text as String)
```

On your button click in page1 use the following code.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
RaiseEvent Textchanged(Me, Textbox2.Text)
End Sub
```

In your main page when you create Page1 add an event handler on the textchanged event

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim page1 As New Page1
    Addhandler page1.Textchanged, AddressOf Changetext
    Frame1.Navigate(page1)
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeText(sender as object, txt as String)
Label1.Content = txt
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for helping Mahabendra and @freschx. I've updated my question because i missed including having two pages. hope u cud still help me. thanks!